# Select in Combo box with mutiple letter entry

Tags: internet-explorer

i have a question, I am not sure if this is a technical one:

I have a combo box in which I want the user to be able to enter 2 or 3 characters and the combo box will step through as the user enters the letters. For example user presses on
"R", "R2F" appears, then the user presses "H", "RH" and all items starting with Rh appears and so on. The tricky part is that this works on my system IE8, am not too sure if this is an IE 8.0 feature or if I need to change any settings. Please advice.

Thanks
Sid

Answer (score 1):

It's default feature in IE8 and Opera, and, quite possibly all other major browsers.

Comment: Is it possible, if I am using older versions to change some settings to get this feature...lets say IE6.0 and above

Comment: No. Its either built in and enabled by default, or you have to fix it with javascript. _I don't have IE6, to check, if it supported this, but i think, it did_.

Answer (score 1):

No but I think you need to create/use javascript to create a custom select list. Very annoying as I have the same problem as you.